# Java: every combination of two arrays

Tags: java

I have 2 arrays (T0, T1, T2) & (R1,R2,R3) I want all 27 combinations of them for example:

```
R1-T1, R1-T2, R1-T3
R1-T1, R1-T2, R2-T3
R1-T1, R1-T2, R3-T3
R1-T1, R2-T2, R1-T3
R1-T1, R2-T2, R2-T3
R1-T1, R2-T2, R3-T3
....
```

I know how to do it with 3 for loops but I need something more flexible that can work with different number of array sizes (e.g. (T0,..T8) & (R1, R2)).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why 3 for-loops?

```
for(int i : array1) {
    for(int j : array2) {
        combinations.add(new Combination(i, j));
    }
}
```

Just as an example...

Comment: What is Combination? Also i thing this will create only 9 alternavies i need all 27

Comment: Ah ok now I get it. I thought you need all combination of possible pairs. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be to convert the arrays into Sets and then use Google Guava's
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.List)

To get the cartesian product.
It has a convinient method for Array -> Set: newHashSet(E... elements)

You should consider to use "standard" libarys to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you could flatmap a stream of elements and build pairs of them like this:

```
final List<Integer> first = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
final List<Integer> second = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

first.stream()
     .flatMap(x -> second.stream().map(y -> Tuple.tuple(x, y)))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What is the "Tuple" here?

Comment: [org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html)

Comment: It is now called Pair. But I guess there is now something called `Entry` in Java? It is a long time ago, since I wrote this answer.